# Riemann integrable functions with end point function value $=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, riemann-integration

Do there exist functions $t\to f(t)$ so that $f(0) = +\infty$ but decaying so fast that the Riemann integral $\int_0^1 f(t)dt$ converges? Maybe my memory betrays me, but I can't think of any such function from my calculus school days.

Wait a minute... isn't $f(t) = -\log(t)$ such a function?

$$\int -\log(t)dt = \left[t-t\log(t)\right]_0^1$$
Which converges by famous limit $$\underset{t\to 0}{\lim}\left\{t\log(t)\right\}=0$$

Do there exist many other examples expressible as (integrals of) elementary functions or is it a special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are such examples. For example, let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$, then
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm d x = 2 $$

In fact, in general if you choose $g_p(x) = 1/x^p$, then the integral
$$\int_0^1 g_p(x)\,\mathrm d x = \frac{1}{1-p} $$
and converges for all $0<p<1$.

Comment: Yep, and also the rest of the family $x^{-1/k}$ as uncovered by Arnaud in previous question. Your new expansion covers more cases than Arnauds one.